# How can I prevent jQuery from running while in edit mode for a Sharepoint web part?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm building a Web site using Sharepoint 2010 and I have created a snazzy jQuery slide show within an Content Editor Web part (using the view HTML code editing option). Works great, except if I want to edit the web part the jQuery runs on the edit screens and causes all sorts of havoc.

My HTML is essentially this:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery is something like this:

```
$('.slideshow').each(function(){
    // Do the magic
});
```

Is there a class or id I can rely on in a Sharepoint 2010 Web part while editing that I can leverage to prevent the jQuery selector from seeing my slideshow? Something like this:

```
$('div:not(.sharepoint-edit-block) .slideshow').each(function(){
    // Do the magic
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not used the hidden input IDs mentioned in the other answer but they are present and would work just as well.

Assuming a publishing page, I have always used the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Only run if page is not in Design Mode
    var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;

    if (inDesignMode !== "1")
    {

        $('.slideshow').each(function(){
            // Do the magic
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

On wiki pages you can check for an element with an ID of `_wikiPageMode`, if you're in edit mode the `value` property will be `Edit` otherwise it will be empty (the empty string).

If you're not on a wiki page, you can look for a form element with an ID of `MSOLayout_InDesignMode`, if you're in edit mode the `value` property will be `1` otherwise it will be empty (the empty string). Wiki pages also have this tag, but it does not have its value set to 1 when the wiki page is in edit mode.Non-wiki pages will not have the `_wikiPageMode` tag and so your selector will be empty (an array of no results), and a call to `val()` will be `undefined`

```
// technique for wiki pages
$("#_wikiPageMode").val() // "Edit" or ""

// technique for non-wiki pages
$("#MSOLayout_InDesignMode").val()  // "1" or ""
```

Comment: The `$("#MSOLayout_InDesignMode").val()  // "1" or ""` worked for me in SharePoint Office 365. Sounds obvious, but check for STRING value of "1" rather than number 1.